# Why won't my POST request update my data.json file?

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch, jsx

So a user should be able to fill the form out and submit, which should update the local JSON server with the new comment. Currently it is not working. I am using the proper port which I checked using json-server --watch db.json. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
class CommentForm extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitted");

    const body = e.target.body.value;

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/comments", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json(); // do something with response JSON
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>What is your favorite breed?</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Answer: </label>
          <br />
          <textarea type="text" name="body" />
          <br />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CommentForm
```

```
{
    "comments": [
      { 
        "text": "Australian Shepherd!"
      },
      { 
        "text": "German Shepherd!"
      },
      { 
        "text": "Mutts all the way"
      },
      { 
        "text": "Chihuahua"
      },
      { 
        "text": "Great Pyrenees rock!!!"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: `Currently it is not working` what does that mean? HTTP error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: CommentForm.js:21 POST http://localhost:3000/comments 404 (Not Found) and Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/comments", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …} and VM479:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Your API (ie- json server) doesn't know what `http POST /comments` means.  You either don't have that route defined, or you're using the wrong method, or some other part of your url is wrong.

Comment: when i look it up in my terminal it shows http://localhost:3000/comments which is what I have so I don't understand

Comment: 404 means that the server can't find the resource you're requesting.  A connection is getting established to whatever is running on port 3000 (otherwise you'd get a response code in the 500's), but what is running there doesn't know what `/comments` is using an HTTP POST request.

Comment: That 2nd error (Syntax Error) is probably your API returning an HTML body in the 404 response when your React code is expecting JSON.

Comment: Is that JSON the entire contents of your db.json file?

Comment: Also, what port is your React app running on?  Typically it will run on port 3000 by default (if you use create-react-app).  It might be that you're making an API request to your UI instead.  Change your json-server port to something like 5000, then change your FETCH url accordingly and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: It's running on 3000. That is all the contents of db.json file

Comment: did not work even with changing the port to something else

Comment: may be worth nothing that my db.json file is also inside the SRC folder

Comment: when i try to move db.json file out of src it throws even more errors